# Apache Zeppelin executors standalong cluster

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I just installed Apache Zeppelin on my Apache standalone cluster, but Zeppelin cannot allocate more than one executors.

I tried setting `spark.executor.instances`, `spark.executor.memory` in the Spark interpreter, but none of it seems to be working.

Any ideas for what I need to do?

Thanks,
- Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed the problem by setting other properties in the Spark interpreter 
UI.

```
spark.executor.cores = 5
spark.executor.instances = 10
spark.executor.memory = 12G
```